# Is a convergent sequence of events always defined by inclusion

Tags: probability

Given a sequence of events $A_n, $  defined by inclusion, for example $A_k\subset A_{k+1}, \forall k\in N $, then the sequence is an increasing or decreasing one and thus convergent. Is the converse also true, i. e. a convergent sequence of events is always of the type defined above by the inclusion? If no, can you provide an example?

Many thanks.

Comment: How is limit of events defined? As the event that infinitely many of the events occur? Or that almost all of the events occur? Anyway, I suppose you could take $A_n=[\frac1n, 1+\frac1n]$.and this should converge to $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence of sets converges if 
$$
\lim\inf A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k=\lim \sup{A_n}
$$
Consider the sequence of events $A_n\subset \mathbb{R}$ given by $A_k=(k, \infty)$, if $k$ is even and $A_k=(-\infty, -k$) if $k$ is odd for $k\geq 0$. Then the limit is given by the empty set and the sequence is neither increasing nor decreasing.

Comment: Maybe you mean $(-\infty, -k)$ rather than $(-k,\infty)$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo

Answer (score 2):

On the sample space of positive integers, consider the events $A_n = \{n\}$.  Then none of the events is included in any other, but the sequence converges to the empty set
(in the sense that every outcome is eventually not in $A_n$).

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate little bit why the limit is the empty set?

Comment: @user249018: "(in the sense that every outcome is eventually not in $A_n$)"

Comment: @user249018 if you want to define the limit using lim sup and lim inf as Foobaz John did, that's easy too.